# Find one (1) book with Google Book api for .Net

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I have been trying for hours but i can't get it working. I use the following code (VB)

```
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim credential As UserCredential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets With {.ClientId = "my key", .ClientSecret = "my secret"}, New String() {BooksService.Scope.Books}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"))
        Dim service As New BooksService(New BaseClientService.Initializer With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = "LibraryX"})

        'Dim bookselve As Bookshelves = Await service.Mylibrary.Bookshelves.List.ExecuteAsync
        Dim mm = service.Volumes.Get("9780330441230")

    End Sub
```

It doesn't give me the information about the book (The Camel Club, David Baldacci)

Can somebody help me?

Greetings,
Steven

20131106

I've made some changes:

Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    Dim credential As UserCredential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets With {.ClientId = "my key", .ClientSecret = "my secret"},
                                                                                         New String() {BooksService.Scope.Books}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"))
    Dim service As New BooksService(New BaseClientService.Initializer With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = "LibraryX"})

    'Dim bookselve As Bookshelves = Await service.Mylibrary.Bookshelves.List.ExecuteAsync
    Try
        rslt = Await service.Volumes.Get("9780330441230").ExecuteAsync
        Dim y As Integer = 0
    Catch gaex As Google.GoogleApiException
        ErrorMessageTextBox.Text = gaex.Message
    Catch ex As AggregateException
        ErrorMessageTextBox.Text = ex.Message
    End Try


End Sub
```

But the result of the request is:

`enter code here`Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The volume ID could not be found. [404]
Errors [
    Message[The volume ID could not be found.] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]

Any idea what the VolumeId must be to get book info from Google??

Comment: The API is looking for a client secret and key.  Did you strip those out of your example above or are you not including them when you try the code?

Comment: Do you get an exception? What is the content of mm?

Comment: Yes i left the key en de secret msg out of this post intentionally.

Comment: ?mm
{Google.Apis.Books.v1.VolumesResource.GetRequest}
    Alt: Nothing
    Country: Nothing
    ETagAction: Default {0}
    Fields: Nothing
    HttpMethod: "GET"
    Key: Nothing
    Logger: {Google.Apis.Logging.NullLogger}
    MethodName: "get"
    OauthToken: Nothing
    Partner: Nothing
    PrettyPrint: Nothing
    Projection: Nothing
    QuotaUser: Nothing
    RequestParameters: Count = 12
    RestPath: "volumes/{volumeId}"
    Service: {Google.Apis.Books.v1.BooksService}
    service: {Google.Apis.Books.v1.BooksService}
    Source: Nothing
    UserIp: Nothing
    VolumeId: "9780330441230"

Answer (score 1):

Got it! You should use the Execute or ExecuteAsync methods on the GetRequest object.
So your last line of code should look like:

`Dim mm = Await service.Volumes.Get("9780330441230").ExecuteAsync()`

Comment: peleyal, many thanks but i am still unable to get book info, see my Original question

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right volume? You are getting 404 which means that this volume doesn't exist. Try get it first with our Google API Explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/books/v1/books.volumes.get) and after you see it works there, you should try the same Id with your code. PLEASE REMOVE YOUR CLIENT SECRETS FROM THE SAMPLE CODE YOU PROVIDED AND DELETE THIS CLIENT, THEN CREATE A NEW ONE. YOU SHOULD NOT PROVIDE THAT INFORMATION ONLINE!

Comment: Hi peleyal, you are wright, i've change my secret key and the program so they wil not show anymore. I have tested your url with al least 15 ISBN numbers and they all returned nothing. I have tested with English and with Dutch books. No results!

Answer (score 0):

I used Google API Explorer and ran the following query in the books.volumes.list method, q=intitle:"The Camel Club";inauthoer:David Baldacci

You can find it in the following link https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/books/v1/books.volumes.list?q=intitle%253A%2522The+Camel+Club%2522%253Binauthor%253A+David+Baldacci&_h=13&.

I'm not an expert of this API, but I found all the required information in https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#PerformingSearch. 
I'm pretty sure that you can optimize the query but it's a good place to start with.

UPDATE (adding .NET code):
Every action which is available using Google API explorer, is also available using the .NET client library, as following:

```
var service = new BooksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        // HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Books API Sample",
    });
var volumes = await service.Volumes.List(
      "intitle:\"The Camel Club\";inauthor: David Baldacci").ExecuteAsync();
foreach (var item in volumes.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.VolumeInfo.Title);
}
```

Notice that we don't need UserCredential in this case, because we don't query user's specific data. If you want to query Mylibrary you should use UserCredential and authenticated request.

Comment: Hey peleyal, I think we are talking different languages. You're talking Comunication via REST, with url e.g. I'm talking finding books via the DOTNET client library. That is a big difference.

Comment: This is going into the wright direction, thanks peleyal.  Still one question: Dim rslt = Await service.Volumes.List("isbn: 9789022992364").ExecuteAsync
            Dim rslt = Await service.Volumes.Get("q=isbn: 9789022992364").ExecuteAsync
The first query gives a result of 3 books of which the first one is the one requested, the second query still produces the 404 Not Found. Do you know what the querystring for the Volumes.Get request must be to obtain a good result?